# PCA for tangent space approximation

Tags: pca, approximation, geometry

Given samples on an $m$-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($m<n$) defined by $C(x)=0$ (not known) where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to perform PCA to approximate the tangent space at $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ using samples in its neighborhood (e.g., all points that satisfy $\|x-x_i\|_2<d$). However, in some cases the number of samples $k$ is smaller than the dimensionality $n$. Thus, the covariance matrix is singular. Is there a way to estimate a full-rank covariance matrix with the given $k$ samples and some assumption on the dimensionality of the manifold that will provide the best PCS approximation?

Comment: It's difficult to see how you could accomplish that in anything but an arbitrary way.  Note, however, that your $k$ samples uniquely determine a subspace $V$ of dimension no larger than $k-1\lt m.$  Why not stop there?  At least you can say that the manifold of possible $m$-dimensional solutions is the Grassmannian of all $m$-dimensional affine subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that contain $V.$

Comment: Sure. That is a nice insight. However, it would not give me anything practical. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you explain why this would not be "practical"?  It certainly delimits the set of all possible solutions, thereby showing what aspect of any answer necessarily depends on the extra assumptions you would need to make in order to obtain a unique solution.